# Loading PNG image in Direct2D without loss of quality

Tags: delphi, direct2d

I have a problem with loading an PNG image with a resolution of 192 dpi. I load an image with WICImage, then I convert it into ID2D1Bitmap. As a result, i have either DPI reduced to 96, or the size of the final image halved. In both cases the image quality gets worse.

The image upload code is as follows:

```
...
private
  FRenderTarget: ID2D1HwndRenderTarget;
  FBitmapD2D: ID2D1Bitmap;
end;
...
procedure TPrimitiveBitmap.LoadBitmapDX(AStream: TStream);
var
  TmpWicFactory: IWICImagingFactory;
  TmpWicImage: TWICImage;
  TmpConverter: IWICFormatConverter;
  TmpProperties: TD2D1BitmapProperties;
  TmpDpiX: Double;
  TmpDpiY: Double;
begin
  TmpWICImage := TWICImage.Create();
  try
    // Reading image
    TmpWicImage.LoadFromStream(AStream);
    // Getting image factory
    TmpWicFactory := TmpWicImage.ImagingFactory;
    // Initializing converter
    TmpWicFactory.CreateFormatConverter(TmpConverter);
    TmpConverter.Initialize(TmpWicImage.Handle,
      GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA,
      WICBitmapDitherTypeNone,
      nil,
      0,
      WICBitmapPaletteTypeMedianCut);
    // Getting current DPI
    TmpConverter.GetResolution(TmpDpiX, TmpDpiY);
    // This resolution need to set when converting. Else 96 DPI will be set by default
    TmpProperties.pixelFormat := D2D1PixelFormat();
    TmpProperties.dpiX := TmpDpiX;
    TmpProperties.dpiY := TmpDpiY;
    // Converting to ID2D1Bitmap
    FRenderTarget.CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(TmpConverter, @TmpProperties, FBitmapD2D);
    // NB! Sizes of FBitmapD2D is halved in comparison to WicImage. It's a problem.
    FSize := TSizeF.Create(TmpWicImage.Width, TmpWicImage.Height);
    FResolution := TPointF.Create(TmpDpiX, TmpDpiX);
  finally
    TmpConverter := nil;
    TmpWicFactory := nil;
    FreeAndNil(TmpWICImage);
  end;
end;
```

The code above illustrates the case when the resolution of 192 DPI will be preserved, but the size will be halved. If you set nil instead of TmpProperties in the CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap call, then the final image will retain its size, but the DPI will be reduced to 96.

What's wrong? How to load a picture correctly without loss of quality?

Comment: Do you have a sample 192 DPI bitmap somewhere?